# Why my jupyter kernel is not visible in vs code jupyter extension?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, kernel

I have my pyspark kernel installed using sparkmgic, it is showing in jupyter notebook and worked fine (connected to remote livy service and ran code without any issues). It is also visible when I use `jupyter kernelspec list` command, but when I tried to use vs code jupyter extension, it is not showing in the kernel list.

What is the reason it could be? how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/8286
Got the answer from the one of code contributors on Github.

Just need to put python full path in the kernel configuration json file.